# Is there a way to access an ITypeDescriptorContext or an IServiceProvider object from a custom TypeDescriptionProvider?

Tags: c#, system.componentmodel

It seems like an odd gap in the `TypeDescriptor` dynamic metadata architecture. All of the `TypeConverter`, `UITypeEditor` and other dynamic designers, editors and converter classes provide access to an `IServiceProvider` object which allows for design context to be passed to implementing classes.

For some reason this is absolutely missing from `TypeDescriptionProvider`, `CustomTypeDescriptor` and associated interfaces. Is there any way to have access to the editor design context while dynamically extending the metadata/properties of a class?

Comment: Could you give a code example how you would use that? I'm talking about a [mcve].

Comment: Minimal *and* complete are contradictory requirements for any example using the component model interfaces. You need at least a site form, something like a property grid, one data model object and three or four concrete implementations of various interfaces to even have anything that will work standalone. That is just the way this specific part of the .NET infrastructure works unfortunately.

Comment: I am fairly familiar with working around this infrastructure, but I was hoping that someone more experienced who may have also stumbled upon this issue would be able to help. Thanks in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking more about it, I concluded that this can be solved by creating a dynamic `TypeDescriptionProvider` implementation which is provided by the designer itself. This implementation can receive a context directly via some domain-specific property.

It is then possible to associate dynamic type description providers using the `TypeDescriptor.AddProvider` method, passing in the custom provider and the target type.